# String to object in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

My webservice return data, I replace unnecessary character and get valid string.

How that string transfer in object.

Example 1 static data (not from web service) work fine.

```
$scope.str = [];
str = {"car": [{"id": 11,"name": "BMW",}, {"id": 22,"name": "Toyota"}],};
$scope.data = str;
```

Example 2 data from web service not working

```
str = data;
str.replace("?", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace(";", "");
$scope.data = str;
```

Comment: Can you post what the response from your web service looks like ?

Comment: Please include a sample web service response in your question.

Comment: You should be more specific.  What doe you mean it is not working?  Did you check to make sure `data` in line 1 of example 2 is not null or undefined?  If it is it will definitely cause problems on the next line.

Comment: Mmmh... if your service return json (string) then you already have an object on client side, no? If it's returning something else, maybe you are creating unnecessary problems for yourself?

Comment: @groooves here is full source:  http://jsbin.com/nuxanayuca/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After cleaning up your string, you just need to run `JSON.parse()`,

try this:

```
str = data;
JSON.parse(str.replace('?','').replace('(','').replace(')','').replace(';','').replace(',}','}').replace(',};','}'))
$scope.data = JSON.parse(str);
```

**REGEX version:**

```
JSON.parse(data.replace(/\?|\(|\)/g, '').replace(/,}/g, '}').replace(/;/g, ''));
```

**Working Copy:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title></title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyController">
  <option ng-repeat="cars in data.car" value="{{cars.name}}">{{cars.name}}</option>

  <button ng-click="calculateQuantity()">Calculate</button>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);

    app.controller("MyController", function($scope, $http) {


      $scope.calculateQuantity = function() {

        $http.get('https://crossorigin.me/http://wsvuci.int-ware.com/appWS.asmx/myService?callback=?', {
            params: {
              userName: 'aa',
              procedureName: "EXECUTE wsReturn"
            }
          })
          .success(function(data) {
            $scope.data = JSON.parse(data.replace(/\?|\(|\)/g, '').replace(/,}/g, '}').replace(/;/g, ''));
          })
          .error(function() {
            alert("error");
          });
      };

    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not working  here is full source  http://jsbin.com/nuxanayuca/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

replace() returns a string. It doesn't store the result in the "str" variable. Try this:

```
str = data;
str = str.replace("?", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace(";", "");
$scope.data = str;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is JSONP format! You don't need to cleanup anything. Just define a valid callback name and use `$http.jsonp ()`. In the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) you'll find also a working sample.